# Unable to run NativeScript Groceries sample app using Genymotion emulator on Windows 10 PC

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to run the NativeScript sample [Groceries app](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries) on my Windows 10 PC with Genymotion emulator. Project is successfully prepared but deployment fails with error

"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matched given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'

I have android sdk v24.0.2 is installed and I am able to successfully run the NativeScript sample tap achievement app.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion has a download that includes VirtualBox. The NS instructions seem to indicate it is optional. However I also had this error and suspect VirtualBox is needed.

Comment: I have Genymotion installed and i am able to run other native script apps except this one.